# Implementing searchview

Tags: android, searchview

I am a beginner in android.I want to implement search view in another activity but its not working..it doesnt go to searchactivity when typing
in my main activity.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, searchactivity.class);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(cn));

        return true;
    }
```

the android menuxml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.ezybzy.sea.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="hu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        />
</menu>
```

the next activity where i want to implement search

```
public class searchactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchactivity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);
        }
    }
    private void doMySearch(String query) {
        Log.d("Event", query);
    }
```

the android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ezybzy.sea">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".searchactivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_searchactivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>



            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" /></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the searchable xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="hellot"
    android:label="hai">
</searchable>
```

Comment: "It isn't working" does not clearly describe the problem.

Comment: i mean it doesnt go to searchactivity

Comment: Do you ever launch an Intent to go to searchactivity? I'm not seeing that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fire an intent to SearchActivity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.search:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class));
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```